# Context-free and regular language decidability

Tags: formal-languages

If L is some context-free language and R is a regular language, I am pretty sure that L ⊆ R is decidable (while R ⊆ L is not) but I am having some difficulty giving an algorithm to prove that it is decidable. Am I right to believe this?

Comment: If you don't have a algorithm in mind, then what makes you "pretty sure" it is decidable?

Comment: I know that one has to be decidable and one is not. I also know that's it undecidable whether a context-free grammar can generates all strings over an alphabet. Therefore, as R can produce all strings over an alphabet, R ⊆ L must be undecidable meaning that  L ⊆ R must be decidable. I'm just not sure how to prove that L ⊆ R is decidable.

Comment: x @user: From where do you know that "one has to be decidable and one is not"? That is not obvious to me.

Comment: It is for a homework for a class. I have to prove that one is decidable and one is not. I have given a proof to prove the one that I believe to be undecidable but I was hoping for some help towards proving the one that I believe to be decidable.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $R$ is regular, so its complement $\overline{R}$ is regular, and thus it’s decidable whether $L\cap\overline{R}=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

What are your tools for proving this? What are the characteristics of a regular or a context free language?
Try to use the machine characterization of regularity and context freeness to build a Turing machine which decides the inclusion you want to prove is decidable. Can you see how to do this?